# Fast hash for std::set<int> of two values?

Tags: c++, stl, hash, dictionary, set

I am using a `std::set<int>` for the key of a std map (`std::unordered_map<std::Set<int>,float>`).  I need a hash for this set.

The set will always be only two integers, whose values could be up to 2 million.

Any ideas on a good and fast hash for such a key as performance is critical?

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly?  You're using a `std::set` as the key to a `TR1:unordered_map`?

Comment: If it's only two integers, why are you not using `std::pair<int, int>` as your key?

Comment: I thought that if I used a pair, I would have problems as for my purposes (a,b) == (b,a) but with a pair this would not be true (I assume).  When I use a set, because the integers are sorted then I won't miss any values in my map accidentally when looking-up

Comment: And in any case, as far as I know there is no build in hash function for pairs of integers, so isn't the question is pretty much the same?

Comment: Good and fast hash? bitwise `|` or `^`? Since you're using a set, you can do some silly things with bit shifting the first value or xoring with different seeds... but hashing functions tend to depend on the underlying distribution of values.

Comment: Skip std::pair<int,int> write your own wrapper class around two integers, implementing the operator==() to do (a,b)==(b,a) or (a,b)==(a,b). Then implement a hash function for that...

Comment: "performance is critical" and `std::set` in the same context. You made my day! :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use boost::hash_combine() : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd ditch the set idea (it is a waste of both memory and time to store two integers in a `std::set`) and go with the pair. Then define

```
template <class A>
struct unordered_pair_hash
{
  std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<A, A>& p) const { 
    using std::min;
    using std::max;
    return std::hash<A>()(min(p.first, p.second))+
        17*std::hash<A>()(max(p.first, p.second));
  }
};

template <class A>
struct unordered_pair_eq
{
  bool operator()(const std::pair<A, A>& p1, const std::pair<A, A>& p2) const {
    using std::min;
    using std::max;
    return min(p1.first, p1.second)==min(p2.first, p2.second) &&
           max(p1.first, p1.second)==max(p2.first, p2.second);
  }
};
```

and then declare the map with a custom hash and equality.

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, float, unordered_pair_hash<int>, unordered_pair_eq<int> > ...
```

Comment: why 17 as the multiple of the second value?

Comment: Much simpler hash function: `std::hash<A> hash; return hash(p.first) + hash(p.second);`. Unsigned addition is a good hash combiner when commutativity is needed (and it is, in this case, because `{1,0}` and `{0,1}` need to hash to the same value).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't exactly state what the purpose of your lookup is,
but maybe you should (or shouldn't):

- simply use a struct { int a, b; } as a key - **you control** the insertion of the members (make sure `a <= b`)
- use a [Sparse Matrix](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/8352/) implementation

Regards

rbo